# DD-WRT/TOMATO Whitelist openVPN connection for specified client MAC/IP

Tags: vpn, iptables, whitelist

I will use these settings:

```
# Allow these TRUSTED hosts unrestricted access 
iptables -A wanout -i `nvram get lan_ifname` -m mac --mac-source <allowed MAC #1> -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A wanout -i `nvram get lan_ifname` -m mac --mac-source <allowed MAC #2> -j ACCEPT 

# Allow everyone access to these sites 
iptables -A wanout -i `nvram get lan_ifname` -d <VPN IP1> -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A wanout -i `nvram get lan_ifname` -d <VPN IP2> -j ACCEPT 

# Everything else gets blocked 
iptables -A wanout -i `nvram get lan_ifname` -j DROP
```

should this work fine?
I'm assuming the vpn address are available on all ports.
and everything else should be blacklisted on all ports.

This should prevent torrenting and any other activity unless done through a VPN unless the mac address is under the trusted list, correct?